# How to add a duplicate class to a DOM object using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class

Lets say I have an element

```
<a class="Foo Bar" />
```

And I want to add a duplicate class, so as I code this:

```
$('.Bar').addClass('Foo');
```

The class is not added, because the element already has one.

I want to code something like this:

```
$('.Bar').addClassForcebly('Foo'); // Fake method, only for example.
```

And I expect the following result:

```
<a class="Foo Bar Foo" />
```

I have tried to use the jQuery's `addClass` method's overload:

```
$('.Bar').addClass(function(i, c) {
    return c + ' Foo';
});
```

But this does not work either. It just does not add the duplicate class. How do I do that?

---

The point of this question is pretty simple: I want to make my HTML elements be able to be disabled and enabled mulitple times. If I 'disable' an element twice (adding two same classes) I should 'enable' it twice as well in order for my logic to work.

Comment: Can you tell what advantage/difference is obtained by having a class duplicated? I can't figure out *any*.

Comment: It's really a browser interpretation problem; you have no point to assign the same class two times to a DOM object.

Comment: I dont think so it is helpful because class is already add once. Is there any specific reason AgentFire

Comment: `$('.bar').attr('class', 'Foo Bar Foo')` should work though...

Comment: Better yet, use counter in attribute like `data-disabled` (really faster then using `.data`).

Comment: @Cthulhu Can I detect a non-zero value in the CSS then?

Comment: `[data-disabled="0"]` for zero, and css has `:not()` for finding non-zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *" If I 'disable' an element twice (adding two same classes) I should 'enable' it twice as well in order for my logic to work."*

You could create your own plugin that keeps track of how many times the class has been added, something like this:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.addClassWithCount = function (className) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this),
                count = $this.data("disable-count-" + className) + 1 || 1;
            $this.data("disable-count-" + className, count);
            $this.addClass(className);
        });
    };
    $.fn.removeClassWithCount = function (className) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this),
                count = $this.data("disable-count-" + className) - 1 || 0;
            if (count < 0) count = 0;
            $this.data("disable-count-" + className, count);
            if (count === 0)
                $this.removeClass(className);            
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Which you'd then use like the standard `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()`:

```
$("someSelector").addClassWithCount("someClass");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Sve9Q/2/

Note that the above is just something I cobbled together quickly to give you the general idea, so obviously it could be prettied up and made more robust.

Answer (score 2):

I dont see any use of it but you can do it by something like using [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
$('.Bar').each(function(){
   this.className = "Foo" + this.className;
});
```

OR, you can use [attr( attributeName, function(index, attr) )](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr) overload that has callback function.

```
$( ".Bar" ).attr( "class", function( i, val ) {
  return "Foo" + val ;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

lets say its the only anchor and you already have this "Foo Bar" added

```
var myAnchor = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
myAnchor.className += " Foo";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that jQuery checks for duplicates when adding classes with addClass, you could just use

```
$('.Bar').each(function(i, e) {

  e.attr('class', e.attr('class') + ' Foo');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

For the use you specified, my opinion is that your best choice should be a class that includes the number of times it has been disabled.

The fist time you add a 'disabled' class.

If an element is already 'disabled' you add a 'disabled2' class (or replace the 'disabled' with 'disabled2') etc...

When re-enabling you do the opposite.

You can use a [class^="disabled"] CSS3 selector to match all the disabled* classes you want to add, without specify them explicitly in your CSS.

Comment: I have a CSS in my site and it does not like these options.

Comment: what options? I'm talking about making CSS class with names

Comment: In case my UI logic decides to disable an element ten times - you advise me to prepeare the CSS for that by creating ten `disabled` classes?

Comment: You don't need to prepare them in advance, if you don't want specific graphic effects you can just add a class to an element even if that class doesn't exist in your CSS

Comment: I don't get it... you can add a 'Foo' class to any DOM element, even if the Foo class doesn't exist in the site CSS. If it does exist, the element will be decorated accordingly, otherwise it will just have a class appended to his class list. You have your disabled class and you add it when you first disable the element, then you can create a CSS rule that match [class^="disabled"] and that will be applied to all disabled* classes. Look at http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings

Comment: Well, I suppose you are right, and the solution has the right to exist, however, checking for `2,3,4` etc suffixes if pretty complicated, so I stay with another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code

```
$(function(){
    alert($(".Bar").attr("class"));

    $(".Bar").attr("class",($(".Bar").attr("class") + ' Foo'));

    alert($(".Bar").attr("class"));

});
```

You can check below link

http://jsfiddle.net/GS43e/